# how to add a space character to trigger var args c++ execlp()

Tags: c++, system-calls, argv

I'm writing this program on Ubuntu.
If I type this command into a shell

> groups root sys bin

it outputs

```
root : root
sys : sys
bin : bin
```

However I'm writing a c++ program that calls groups with execlp using

```
execlp("groups", "groups", args.c_str(), NULL);
```

where args = "root sys bin". I just get a :No such user error since groups' is obviously just looking at that entire string as argv[0] which is the equivalent of running

```
groups "root sys bin"
```

**How** do i create the proper variable argument for execlp to run groups on each user, one at a time?

Comment: try `execlp("groups", "groups", "root", "sys", "bin", "null");`

Comment: I think the last argument should be `NULL` (a null pointer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to ask `/bin/sh` to deal with the input the way it normally would.  Of course in addition to dealing with spaces, this would also deal with characters like `$`, `#`, `~`, `*`, etc., which may or may not be what you want.

```
execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", ("groups " + args).c_str(), nullptr);
```

Obviously, don't use this way if the data is user-entered and might contain nasty strings like:

```
root ;rm *
```

Otherwise, `execl` type functions won't work unless you know the number of command-line arguments at compile time.  Assuming your `args` string could have varying numbers of arguments, you'll need `execv` type functions instead.

```
std::string args = "root sys bin";

std::vector<std::string> arg_vec;
std::istringstream arg_iss(args);
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(arg_iss),
          std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
          std::back_inserter(arg_vec));

char groups_exec[] = "groups";
std::vector<char*> arg_ptr_vec{ groups_exec };
std::for_each(arg_vec.begin(), arg_vec.end(),
              [&](std::string& arg){ arg_ptr_vec.push_back(&arg[0]); } );
arg_ptr_vec.push_back(nullptr);
execvp("groups", arg_ptr_vec.data());
```

Comment: there's no user input in this program actually. BUT, the first code snipet is a perfect solution for me. Thanks!

Comment: actually I wound up using the execvp solution. Still Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The args parameter to execlp is defined as "char *const argv[]", so I think you could do something like

const char *myArgs[3] = {"root, "sys", "bin"};

and then replace args.c_str() with myArgs.

I should admit to having zero experience of writing software for Ubuntu - this is what I would try next were I trying to get execlp to work.

EDIT: This is wrong - I had got mixed up and was looking at execv(), bobah and sleepy42 seem to have got it.